# how to show msgbox on button click event if i have some disabled checkboxes and user forgot to check checkboxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i m using asp.net Usercontrols How to show alert msgbox if user doesn't select atleast minimun 1 checkbox from asp.net checkboxes

if i have disabled some checkboxes on page load event then after user forgot to check checkboxes and click on button then still msgbox will popup "you haven't select checkboxes"

please edit my this code ...to show msg box on button click event if i have disabled checkboxes and if user haven't select any of the checkbox

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="_35seater_WebUserControl" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>
       <div id="s" style="width: 499px">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="77px">
                <table class="style66">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style68" rowspan="2">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/streer.gif" />
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="5" style="background-color: #E4E4E4">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="style106">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Height="33px" 
                                Text="1" Width="33px" />
                            <cc1:ToggleButtonExtender ID="CheckBox1_ToggleButtonExtender" runat="server" 
                                CheckedImageUrl="images/selected.gif" 
                                DisabledUncheckedImageUrl="images/disabled.gif" Enabled="True" ImageHeight="33" 
                                ImageWidth="33" TargetControlID="CheckBox1" 
                                UncheckedImageUrl="images/booked.gif"></cc1:ToggleButtonExtender>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="style106">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Height="33px" 
                                Text="3" Width="33px" />
                            <cc1:ToggleButtonExtender ID="CheckBox3_ToggleButtonExtender" runat="server" 
                                CheckedImageUrl="images/selected.gif" 
                                DisabledUncheckedImageUrl="images/disabled.gif" Enabled="True" ImageHeight="33" 
                                ImageWidth="33" TargetControlID="CheckBox3" 
                                UncheckedImageUrl="images/booked.gif"></cc1:ToggleButtonExtender>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="style106">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox10" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Height="33px" 
                                Text="10" Width="33px" />
                            <cc1:ToggleButtonExtender ID="CheckBox10_ToggleButtonExtender" runat="server" 
                                CheckedImageUrl="images/selected.gif" 
                                DisabledUncheckedImageUrl="images/disabled.gif" Enabled="True" ImageHeight="33" 
                                ImageWidth="33" TargetControlID="CheckBox10" 
                                UncheckedImageUrl="images/booked.gif"></cc1:ToggleButtonExtender>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                                  </tr>
                </table>
                <hr style="width: 494px; height: -15px" />
                <table class="style99" style="text-align: center; height: 10px;">
                    <tr class="style102">
                        <td class="style103" style="text-align: center; " colspan="3">
                            <table class="style113">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style116">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; color: #990000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;" 
                                            Text="Select Boarding Point :"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="style115">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" 
                                            style="font-weight: 700; color: #990000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;" 
                                            Text="Select Dropping Point :"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" ForeColor="White" 
                                            style="font-size: xx-small" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style114" style="text-align: right">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="bd_time" DataValueField="bd_time" 
                                            style="margin-left: 0px; " Width="240px">
                                            <asp:ListItem>Choose...</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                                            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [bd_time] FROM [boardingpt] WHERE ([service] = @service)">
                                            <SelectParameters>
                                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label22" Name="service" PropertyName="Text" 
                                                    Type="String" />
                                            </SelectParameters>
                                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="dp_time" DataValueField="dp_time" 
                                            style="margin-left: 0px; " Width="240px">
                                            <asp:ListItem>Choose...</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                                            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [dp_time] FROM [droppingpt] WHERE ([service] = @service)">
                                            <SelectParameters>
                                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label22" Name="service" PropertyName="Text" 
                                                    Type="String" />
                                            </SelectParameters>
                                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style114" colspan="2" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 12px;">
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"  OnClientClick ="return checkboxChecked();" runat="server" 
                                            ImageUrl="~/images/redContinueButton.gif" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style114" colspan="2" style="text-align: left">
                                        <div style="visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden">
                                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
                                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="sel_seat" 
                                                DataValueField="sel_seat" Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="Maroon" 
                                                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                            <br />
                                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server" 
                                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="seats" DataValueField="seats" 
                                                Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="Maroon" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                                                RepeatLayout="Flow">
                                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 1 [seats], [id], [dates], [service]
FROM            a1_holds
WHERE        (dates = @dates) AND (service = @service) ORDER BY [id] DESC">
                                                <SelectParameters>
                                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label25" Name="dates" PropertyName="Text" />
                                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label22" Name="service" PropertyName="Text" />
                                                </SelectParameters>
                                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT sel_seat
FROM            a1_ticket
WHERE        (journey_date = @journey_date) AND (serv_code = @serv_code)">
                                                <SelectParameters>
                                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label25" Name="journey_date" 
                                                        PropertyName="Text" />
                                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label22" Name="serv_code" 
                                                        PropertyName="Text" />
                                                </SelectParameters>
                                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="style102">
                        <td class="style100">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BorderColor="White" 
                                BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" ReadOnly="True" 

                                style="font-size: small; text-align: center; font-weight: 700; color: #FFFFFF;"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style112">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" 
                                style="font-size: small; font-weight: 700; color: #FFFFFF;"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style110">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" 
                                style="font-size: small; font-weight: 700; color: #FFFFFF;"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkboxChecked(){
    var checked=false;
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var noOfChkBox = 0; // number of check box
    var noOfDisabledChkBox = 0; // number of disabled check box

    for(var i=0; i<allInputs.length; i++){
         var chk=allInputs[i];
         if(chk.type == "checkbox"){
            noOfChkBox++;
            if(chk.disabled){
                noOfDisabledChkBox++;
            }

            if(chk.checked){
               checked=true;
               break;
            }
         } 
    }
    if(noOfDisabledChkBox===noOfChkBox)
    {
        checked=true; 
    }
    if(!checked)
        alert("OOps! You haven't select checkboxes");
    return checked;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your js.Please chk and revert if it works

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkboxChecked(){
    var checked=false;
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var noOfChkBox = 0; // number of check box
    var noOfDisabledChkBox = 0; // number of disabled check box

    for(var i=0; i<allInputs.length; i++){
         var chk=allInputs[i];
         if(chk.type == "checkbox"){
            noOfChkBox++;
            if(chk.disabled){
                noOfDisabledChkBox++;
            }

            if(chk.checked){
               checked=true;
               break;
            }
         } 
    }
    if(noOfDisabledChkBox===noOfChkBox)
    {
        checked=true; 
    }
    if(!checked)
        alert("OOps! You haven't select checkboxes");
    return checked;
}
</script>
```

Comment: var allInputs = getElementById("input");

this code will be highlighted with yellow color and dispalys an erro object expected

Comment: have a look of attached imaged on my code .. my checkboxes are attached with ajaxtoolkit tooogle extender

Comment: changed , please check.
If you still get an error , I would like to have a look at the generated HTML code!!

Comment: is still redirect to other page on both conditions.. i have update by code above ...

Comment: one more thing ... if all the chekboxes are unchecked then its works fine , whenever i retrieve the data from database and make some checkbox disabled it doesn't works

Comment: how to do that .. if checkboxes are checked n disabled already on pageload then it shows msg box ... else redirect to different page ..

Comment: the checkbox displayed in red above in image are checked n disabled form ... i wanna show msg box if user doesn't check any checkbox intead of red checkboxes

Comment: i wanna validate the checkboxes which have both property checked and disabled and uncked

Comment: Why would you want to check if disabled checkboxes are checked ? There is no way any user can check/uncheck them